# Repeating custom error message using "Yup"

Tags: javascript, node.js, yup

I am throwing error messages using the given code:

```js
const mySchema= Yup.number()
  .typeError('This is the custom error message.')
  .min(500, 'This is the custom error message.')
  .required('This is the custom error message.')
```

The error text is just repeating and being messy as the schema grows.
How can I set custom error for all of the errors?